# Calculating how often pixel had negative NDVI anomalies in last 20 years

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi

I have 20 years of NDVI data, and I've calculated anomalies. I would like to map how frequently each pixel had negative anomaly values since 2002.

I have calculated NDVI anomalies using this code:

```
// NDVI anomaly

// Define country boundary
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Ethiopia'));

// Upload NDVI 
var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13A1')
  .filterBounds(mask)
  .select('NDVI');
  
// Long-term mean
var means = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1,12)
  .map(function(m) {
    return modisNDVI.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      .mean()
      .set('month', m)
}));

var start = ee.Date('2002-01-01');
var months = ee.List.sequence(0, 250);
var dates = months.map(function(index){
  return start.advance(index, 'month');
});
print(dates);

// Group by month
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  dates.map(function(date) {
    var beginning = date;
    var end = ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'month');
    var mean = modisNDVI.filterDate(beginning, end)
    .mean()
    .set('date', date);
  
  var month = ee.Date(date).getRelative('month', 'year').add(1);
  return mean.subtract(
    means.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first())
    .set('date', date);
}));
print(byMonth)

// Add layers to map
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()).clip(mask),{min: -0.3, max: 0.3, palette: ['FF0000', '000000', '00FF00']}, 'EVI anomaly');
Map.centerObject(mask, 6);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: byMonth,
  region: mask,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500, 
  xProperty: 'date'
});

print(chart);
```

How do I proceed from here?

I guess one way to do it is to reclassify all rasters since 2002 so that positive values become 0 and negative values become 1, and then add all rasters. The final output would then be a sum indicating how frequently pixels had a negative classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I think the solution you suggested in your question is the way to go. Thus, you will need to map a function that converts the negative values into 1 and then reduce the ImageCollection to perform a sum over all the images in the collection. I added an additional counter to the results to keep track of the total number of observations. In this way, you can calculate the proportion of negatives values over the total number of observations (which I think might be more informative). Oh, an lastly I inverted the colors in your palette to associate red with negative values and green to positive values.

```
// Map a function to return negative values as 1
// and add a band equal to 1 in all pixels to keep
// a record of the total number of observations
var negatives = byMonth.map(function(image){
  // Values of interest; returns  binary image
  // 1: values of interest, 0: other values
  var negatives = ee.Image(image).lt(0);
  var total = ee.Image.constant(1);
  return negatives.addBands(total)
                  // rename bands
                  .rename(['negatives', 'total'])
                  // copy properties of original image
                  .copyProperties(ee.Image(image));
});

// Show first image
Map.addLayer(ee.Image(negatives.first()).clip(mask),{
  bands: 'negatives',
  min: 0, 
  max: 1, palette: ['00FF00', '000000', 'FF0000']}, 
'EVI anomaly negatives');

// Reduce the negatives collection using the sum Reducer
var sumIm = negatives.sum();
// Calculate the percentage of negative observations / total observations 
sumIm = sumIm.expression('neg / total',
                          {
                            'neg': sumIm.select('negatives'),
                            'total': sumIm.select('total')
                          })
              // rename band            
             .rename('percent');

// Show the percentage image
Map.addLayer(sumIm.clip(mask),{
  bands: 'percent',
  min: 0.3, 
  max: 0.7, 
  palette: [ '00FF00', '000000', 'FF0000']}, 
  'EVI anomaly sum');
```